# Error using MongoDB.Web: MongoDB.Driver.SafeModeResult MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert(!!0)

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the following error using the MongoDB.Web membership provider:

```
Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.SafeModeResult MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert(!!0)'.
```

I have the simplest of implementations:

- Visual Studio Express 2012
- Empty Website project (VB.NET) with a standard index.aspx added
- Nuget packages: MongoDB.Web 1.2, mongocsharpdriver 1.7
- MongoDB db version 2.2.3
- Windows 7 64-bit

(All Mongo elements downloaded fresh today.)

I copied and pasted the Membership provider web.config details from the [FreshLogic](https://github.com/freshlogic/MongoDB.Web) site, and modified only the `database` and `collection` attributes to reference my desired collection.

I have one line of code in the `Page.Load` event of my index.aspx:

```
Membership.CreateUser("fred124243", "Passw0rd$123")
```

I get the aforementioned error when I run the solution. I can see that my collection gets created, so the solution is communicating with MongoDB.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... I had to download MongoDB.Web source from Git and recompile.